# django: how to simultaneously render and redirect to the desired page

Tags: html, django, redirect, rendering

I need to render and redirect the page CreateOrder.html at path: "/order/", after click the form submit button. is there a way to do the rendering and redirecting at the same time? (i.e. update the CreateOrder.html and redirect to this page)

```
def CreateOrder(request):
    navi_load = request.session['navi_load']
    navi_unload = request.session['navi_unload']
    dist = request.session['dist']
    charge = request.session['charge']
    return render(request, 'OnlinePricing/CreateOrder.html', {'pickup_address': navi_load,
                                                                        'delivery_address': navi_unload,
                                                                        'distance': dist, 'charge': charge})


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.OnlinePricing, name='OnlinePricing'),
    path('order/', views.CreateOrder, name='CreateOrder'),
]
```

Comment: You can redirect with `kwargs` and template there should fetch changes it and show them. Interfering with `.html` directly may not be something you want to do.

Comment: tried giving a name to your url path?

Comment: could you be more specific, better with examples. it's difficault to guess what you mean

Comment: have added the urlpatterns